# How do I segue from a programmatically created UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, swift2

I'm working on an app that has a menu that slides in from the left. The menu built programatically using a [UITableView](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/036fff790d50ab6e5b5b) and an [NSObject](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/c741e6be1e6b80e2d94e). I've been able to populate the slide out menu with items but I don't know how to create a segue with an Identifier without using Interface Builder.

Here's what I am tying to do in my tableView:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cellForRow = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    let cellLabel = cellForRow?.textLabel?.text

    delegate?.sideBarControlDidSelectRow(indexPath, cellName: cellLabel!)  

    if (cellLabel == "Item1") {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("item1Settings", sender: nil)
    } else {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("item2Settings", sender: nil)
    }

}
```

*( gist: [SideBarTableViewController](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/036fff790d50ab6e5b5b))*

When I click a cell in the menu I get the following error:

> 2015-06-11 18:35:28.720 SideBarApp[2862:1111870] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   'Receiver () has no
>   segue with identifier 'item1Settings''
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1822882d8 0x193aac0e4 0x186fe4c00 0x10000b030 0x10000b108 0x186df1474 0x186eab790 0x186d4c240
>   0x186cbc6ec 0x1822402a4 0x18223d230 0x18223d610 0x1821692d4
>   0x18b97f6fc 0x186d2efac 0x1000147cc 0x19412aa08) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

After searching stack I found a few solutions in Objective-C but nothing for Swift with this scenario.

**How do I segue from a programmatically created UITableView?**

---

This is where I assemble the UITableView programmatically:

**SideBar.swift** [View Entire File](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/c741e6be1e6b80e2d94e)

```
func setupSideBar(){

    sideBarContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(-barWidth - 1, originView.frame.origin.y, barWidth, originView.frame.size.height)
    sideBarContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    sideBarContainerView.clipsToBounds = false

    originView.addSubview(sideBarContainerView)

    let blurView:UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light))
    blurView.frame = sideBarContainerView.bounds
    sideBarContainerView.addSubview(blurView)


    sideBarTableViewController.delegate = self
    sideBarTableViewController.tableView.frame = sideBarContainerView.bounds
    sideBarTableViewController.tableView.clipsToBounds = false
    sideBarTableViewController.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
    sideBarTableViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    sideBarTableViewController.tableView.scrollsToTop  = false
    sideBarTableViewController.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(sideBarTableViewTopInset, 0, 0, 0)

    sideBarTableViewController.tableView.reloadData()
   sideBarContainerView.addSubview(sideBarTableViewController.tableView)

    }
```

Here is where I call it:

**ViewController.swift** (initial view)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image2")
    sideBar = SideBar(sourceView: self.view, menuItems: ["first item", "second item", "funny item", "another item"])
    sideBar.delegate = self

    }
```

Comment: A segue is used between viewController?Do you mean your `settings1` or `settings2` viewController is created by code?

Comment: It's a bit confusing to me, I'm pretty new to swift. But the sidebar is called in the initial viewDidLoad. This creates the UITableView programatically. There is no storyboard entity for the TableViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it looks like you're trying to do is open a settings page when you select a cell. To do this, you need to define a new UIViewController to hold the settings page code. Also create a UIStoryboardSegue to connect the current UIViewController and your new SettingsViewController.

Then, using `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)` you can get the SettingsViewController just before it is opened, set whatever properties you need to on it, and let it finish launching with this new data at its disposal. Some data you might pass along could contain information telling the SettingsViewController which cell was selected, and what interface it should therefor offer to the user.

If that isn't working out for you, you can instantiate the SettingsViewController, set properties on it, and when you're ready, call `currentController.presentViewController(settingsController, animated: blah, completion: blah)`

Comment: 'UIStoryboardSegue to connect the current UIViewController and your new SettingsViewController.' I've tried this, but I'll try it again now. Edit: and actually my sender was set to nil before.

Comment: Be sure to set `sender` to `self`.

Comment: Didn't work... getting the same error I listed in my OP

Comment: A better way would be to instantiate the SettingsViewController, set whatever properties you may need, then call `currentController.presentViewController(settingsController, animated: blah, completion: blah)`

Comment: you can edit your answer if you want, I'll try your method, it it works well. I'll mark this as the answer. The segue works now that I moved it.

Comment: Just tagged that onto the end. Let me know how it turns out!

Comment: thanks jonah, this answer was super helpful. I used self.presentViewController and it worked like a charm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80421/discussion-between-jonah-and-dan-beaulieu).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an segue with the identifier `item1Settings`? To check select your segue and check in the identifier is set to `item1Settings`. It seems that swift is not finding this name setup in your storyboard.

[image]

Comment: This is my point, the table view is created programmatically. Therefore the entities you're showing in the photo don't exist until runtime

Comment: Where are you creating it? In this case you shouldn't use performSegueWithIdentifier, just push the table view after you create it

Comment: I've included two github-gist files that show where the table view is being created.

Comment: sorry I can't see where you are creating a UITableViewController, maybe you need to explain a little bit more what view pushes what view, etc. But basically you should create the table view and push it.

Comment: Your sideView is not a controller so you can't push it, you can add its view to the view of the controller you have already, your you can inherit from UIViewController or UITableViewController as push the new controller on top of the old controller.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... I needed to perform the segue from my viewController not my SideBarTableViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SideBarDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sideBar = SideBar(sourceView: self.view, menuItems: ["Item1", "item2"])
        sideBar.delegate = self
    }

    func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(index: Int) {

        if (index == 0) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("item1", sender: self)
        } else {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("item2", sender: self)
        }

    }
```